# Generalized Extreme Value Distribution - Criterion

Tags: distributions, modeling, matlab, histogram

I am fitting a distribution to a histogram which looks very non-Gaussian. The histogram was formed by imaging data, i.e., the values of each pixel in an image, so they aren't "extreme values".

By using the command "fithist" in MATLAB as a start, "Generalized Extreme Value Distribution" appeared to describe the histogram the best.

I would like to know whether the Generalized Extreme Value Distribution can be applied to this way, i.e., not minima/maxima of a very large collection of random observations, but a histogram formed by thousands of pixels in an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although extreme value distributions are limiting distributions for extremes, they can be used also for other purposes.  For example, the Weibull distribution is used a lot for reliability problems.  In extreme value theory, there are three types of distributions, the type depends on the population distribution's tail behavior.  I think the term generalized extreme value distribution just refers to a family that encompasses all three types.

Comment: I did my PhD dissertation in extreme value theory.  I got a downvote.  Can someone explain if I misinterpreted the term.  The Weibull is in the family of extreme value distributions and it can be used as a population distribution in reliability.  That would be an example that is not a minimum or maximum for a large number of random variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Michael!  After I posted the question, I looked into it further: I wonder about the downvote too...

Comment: @TTZ Was my interpretation about Generalized Extreme Value Distribution what you had in mind?  Does the Weibull meet your conditions?

Comment: @"Michael Chernick" Apologies for not replying earlier - got sidetracked... You interpretation was what I have in my mind too.  I was looking for a paper etc which demonstrated the use of Generalized Extreme Value distribution in non-extreme data, i.e., not from the maxima/minima, as a reference.  I am wondering whether your thesis contains such an example or do you have any recommendation? Thank you!  My data fit Extreme Value Distribution well on Matlab; not very well with Weibull though...

Comment: @TTZ It would be nice if you would accept my answer.  My dissertation gave examples of sequences of dependent random variables where Gnedenko's theorem can be extended. Ross Leadbetter developed conditions for stationary sequences (special forms of mixing conditions) for Gnedenko's theorem to extend to these type of sequences.  I gave examples where both of his conditions were satisfied and the results extended. I also looked at examples to show what can happen when one of the conditions is not satisfied. The results of Gnedenko and others shows GEVs are the limiting dist. for min. and max.